# CSS: Sidebar 100% display height without overlapping navigation bar. (individual nav height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to build a specific layout for a settings view. This is how it should look like:
[image: Mockup]

There is a **fixed navigation** bar on the **left** side and the **content** on the **right** can be **scrolled independently**. The navigation bar on the left should always fill the complete page except the navigation bar.

I know, I could make the left navigation `position:fixed` and give it an offset of the top-navigation height, but the height of the navigation **changes dynamically**.

So is there any dynamic solution?

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.lorem {
  background-color: Gainsboro;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#nav-top {
  height: 100px;
  Background-color: SeaGreen;
}

#nav-sub {
  height: 30px;
  Background-color: YellowGreen;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.left-nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: Teal;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-top"> Navigation</div>
<div id="nav-sub"> Subnavigation</div>
<ul class="left-nav">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Scrollable Content</h1>
  <div class="lorem">
  </div>
  <div class="lorem">
  </div>
  <div class="lorem">
  </div>
  <div class="lorem">
  </div>
  <div class="lorem">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the link to my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL3cjf9k/):
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/webbm/rL3cjf9k/2/

Comment: @webbm Almost, I still can't scroll the content with this solution. The content below the first ipsum div is not visible and can't be scrolled into the view.

Comment: What causes the height of the header to change dynamically? Upon user action on a page? Page to page content?

Comment: @Jon P  In the real application there are some media queries and user actions changing elements inside the header, which results in a dynamic height I can't predict for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a table instead?

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1{
  margin:0;
}

.lorem{
  background-color: Gainsboro;
  height: 100px;
  margin:10px;
}

#nav-top{
  height:100px;
  Background-color:SeaGreen;
}
#nav-sub{
  height:30px;
  Background-color:YellowGreen;
}

.content{
  width:100%;
}

.left-nav {
  background-color: Teal;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-top"> Navigation</div>
<div id="nav-sub"> Subnavigation</div>

<table><tr class="left-nav">
<td>
  <ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</td>
<td class="content">
  <div >
      <h1>Scrollable Content</h1>
      <div class="lorem">
      </div>
          <div class="lorem">
      </div>
          <div class="lorem">
      </div>
          <div class="lorem">
      </div>
          <div class="lorem">
      </div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't know how you would do this with tables. To get the td height to the desired height results in the same problem again. Your code results in strange behavior. It does not look like the mockup I drew.

Comment: @HelloWorld0815  I updated the code, that should look better.

Comment: Almost, I want the left navigation to be sticky, so that the items are always visible while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Apply width and height to body, and apply fixed dimensions to the header, sidebar and main content.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(103, 194, 33);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5%;
}

aside {
  width: 20%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background-color: rgb(159, 159, 159);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:  column;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  padding: 5%;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2.5%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<header>Brand</header>
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</aside>
<main>
  <h1>Some Content</h1>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: I don't know the header height as it changes dynamically. I also want the header to have a static height, to ensure it has the same height on mobile and desktop. So I can't use % values instead i need to stick to absolute values. In addition this solution is hard to apply to my setup, as the elements are wrapped into more tags. To get it work with 100% I would need to set every parent div to 100% height, too. (Breaking other things)

Comment: If you don't know the header height, why are you setting it to 100px for? The percentage value is not necessary. You can set it to any height you want. I will update the code to show that. And for other things, you need update your code if you want to fit them in your scrollable portion anyway

Comment: I set it to 100px to keep the example as easy as possible and reduce it to its core "problem". In the real application there are some media queries  and user actions changing elements inside the header, which results in a dynamic height I can't predict for sure.
Also   `height: calc(100% - 100px);` would need me to know the offset is 100px.

Comment: In that case, apply min-height to header, and max height to sidebar and main. I have updated the code